# PHP Convert from strtotime into time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to add multiple time values as in Hours:mins, so I use

```
strtotime($value1) + strtotime($value2)
```

to add all of them, how do I put them back as hours:mins ?

cant use

```
date("h:i")
```

it only works if hours < 24.

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: How difficult is it to transform seconds (60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour) to hours?

Comment: seems like the only way, I thought there must be some built in function. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function strtotime() returns the time in seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. So adding the return value of this function might not do what you would expect.

Instead of using the date functions we can manipulate the string and perform some basic arithmetic operations:

```
<?php
$value1 = "12:44";
$value2 = "13:47";

$arr1 = explode(':', $value1);
$arr2 = explode(':', $value2);

$totalMinutes = (int)$arr1[0] * 60 + (int)$arr1[1] + (int)$arr2[0] * 60 + (int)$arr2[1];

$hours = (int) ($totalMinutes / 60);
$minutes = $totalMinutes % 60; // Modulus: remainder when dividing with 60

echo $hours . ':' . $minutes;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an function that will **sum all your time values** in format `HH:MM`:

```php
function sum_time() {
    $i = 0;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $time) {
        sscanf($time, '%d:%d', $hour, $min);
        $i += $hour * 60 + $min;
    }
    if ($h = floor($i / 60)) {
        $i %= 60;
    }
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $i);
}

// use example
echo sum_time('01:05', '00:02', '05:59'); # 07:06
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/98249)</kbd>

Comment: @Digitalfortress: you should always check all answers before accepting one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function time_convert($s) { 
    $m = 0; $hr = 0; $td = "now";
    if ($s > 59) { 
        $m = (int)($s/60); 
        $s = $s-($m*60); // sec left over 
        $td = "$m min"; 
    } 
    if ($m > 59) { 
        $hr = (int)($m / 60); 
        $m = $m - ($hr*60); // min left over 
        $td = "$hr hr"; 
        if ($hr > 1) {
            $td .= "s";
        }
        if ($m > 0) {
            $td .= ", $m min";
        }
    } 

    return $td; 
}
```

And use it:

```
$time = (int) strtotime($v1) + strtotime($v2);
echo time_convert($time);
```

May it helps

Answer (score 0):

Another way with DateTime

```
$dt1 = new DateTime($value1);
$dt2 = new DateTime($value2);
$interval = $dt1->diff($dt2);
echo $interval->format('%a day(s) %h hour(s) %i minute(s)') . '<br />';
echo ($interval->format('%a') * 24 + $interval->format('%h')) . ' hour(s) ';
echo $interval->format('%i minute(s)');
```