# How to sum N number of time (HH:MM Format)?

Tags: php, time, sum

I am using the following sample code to calculate sum of two different time values. Now I want to get the sum of N number of time values.

```
// numbers for testing
$o="12:59";
$p="0:58";

// display for testing
echo "$o<br />";
echo "$p<br />";
echo AddPlayTime($o,$p);

// FUNCTION - ADD HOURS and MINUTES
function AddPlayTime ($oldPlayTime, $PlayTimeToAdd) {
  $old=explode(":",$oldPlayTime);
  $play=explode(":",$PlayTimeToAdd);

  $hours=$old[0]+$play[0];
  $minutes=$old[1]+$play[1];

  if($minutes > 59){
    $minutes=$minutes-60;
    $hours++;
  }

  if($minutes < 10){
    $minutes = "0".$minutes;
  }

  if($minutes == 0){
    $minutes = "00";
  }

  $sum=$hours.":".$minutes;
  return $sum;
}
```

Comment: instead of checking if minutes are less then 10 you can have a look at [number_format](http://ch2.php.net/number_format) function

Comment: and for N numbers of time you can add all your values to an array then pass it to the function.

Comment: @ponciste Thanks for your response, How to do that with array?

Comment: possible duplicate of **[PHP Convert from strtotime into time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21573480/67332)**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

this should do what you are looking for:

`$times` is the array of times and you can add how many time you want

```
$times = array();

$times[] = "12:59";
$times[] = "0:58";
$times[] = "0:02";

// pass the array to the function
echo AddPlayTime($times);

function AddPlayTime($times) {
    $minutes = 0; //declare minutes either it gives Notice: Undefined variable
    // loop throught all the times
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
    }

    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;

    // returns the time already formatted
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}
```

**EDIT**

I edited the code with the right names of the variables. It is more correct now.

hope this helps :-)

Comment: @user3239311 i edited the code with the right name of variables, i did i mistake in the previous code. Now it's more correct :) and i'm glad that was what you needed!

Comment: getting this notice: **Undefined variable: minutes**

Answer (score 7):

Here is an function that will **sum all your time values** in format `HH:MM`:

```php
function sum_time() {
    $i = 0;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $time) {
        sscanf($time, '%d:%d', $hour, $min);
        $i += $hour * 60 + $min;
    }
    if ($h = floor($i / 60)) {
        $i %= 60;
    }
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $i);
}

// use example
echo sum_time('01:05', '00:02', '05:59'); # 07:06
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/98249)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumarHoras($acumuladoTime, $nuevoTime){

    //Se esperan parametros así:
    //$acumuladoTime="02:45";
    //$nuevoTime="04:36";
    //echo "Hora acumulada: $acumuladoTime"."<br>";
    //echo "Nuevo tiempo acumulado: $nuevoTime"."<br>";

    /*Tiempo acumulado*/
    $myArrayAcumuladoTime=explode(":", $acumuladoTime);

    $hrsAcumuladoTime=$myArrayAcumuladoTime[0];
    $minsAcumuladoTime=$myArrayAcumuladoTime[1];

    /*Nuevo Time*/
    $myArrayNewTime=explode(":", $nuevoTime);

    $hraNewTime=$myArrayNewTime[0];
    $minNewTime=$myArrayNewTime[1];

    /*Calculo*/
    $sumHrs=$hrsAcumuladoTime+$hraNewTime;
    $sumMins=$minsAcumuladoTime+$minNewTime;

    /*Si se pasan los MINUTOS*/
    if($sumMins>59){
      /*Quitamos hora para dejarlo en minutos y se la sumamos a la de horas*/
      $sumMins-=60;
      $sumHrs+=1;
    }

    // echo "Total hrs agregadas: $sumHrs:$sumMins"."<br>";
    return "$sumHrs:$sumMins";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way:

```
<?php

    function CalculateTime($times) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($times as $time) {
            sscanf($time, '%d:%d', $hour, $min);
            $i += $hour * 60 + $min;
        }

        if($h = floor($i / 60)) {
            $i %= 60;
        }

        return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $i);
    }

    $date[] = '02:32';
    $date[] = '01:29';
    echo CalculateTime($date);

?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why this is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Framework (PHP language)

```
     $chores = ChoresTime::where('family_id', $family->id)->get();
        $total = [];
        foreach ($chores as $key => $value) {
            $total[] = $value->time;
        }
      $total = CalculateTime($chores);
      return response()->json([
          'status' => 1, 
          'message' => 'Total Time', 
          'data' => [], 
          'total' => $total 
      ], ok());
```

Answer:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Family Total Chores Time",
    "data": [],
    "total": "14:22"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the above sum_time function to seconds:

```
function sum_time()
{
    $hh = 0;
    $mm = 0;
    $ss = 0;
    foreach (func_get_args() as $time)
    {
       sscanf( $time, '%d:%d:%d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
       $hh += $hours;
       $mm += $mins;
       $ss += $secs;
    }

    $mm += floor( $ss / 60 ); $ss = $ss % 60;
    $hh += floor( $mm / 60 ); $mm = $mm % 60;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hh, $mm, $ss);
}
```