# Looping array sum per row (array[0] + array[1] = $a) then $a + array[2]) php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, sum

I have a problem with my code.

This rule for my array loop:

[image]

I have tried like this :

```
 $line_1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loading_plan WHERE line='1' ORDER BY id_load asc");
$total_hr_21 = Array();
while ($l1=mysql_fetch_array($line_1)){
$total_hr[] = $l1[total_hr];
}
```

This code just describes the array number, but I don't have any idea how to sum this  `"$l1[total_hr];"` per row like in my rule.

**[EDIT]**

I was implement answer from Karthick Kumar to my coding, that just using `array_sum($total_hr_21);` and it's work for my rule. so this is my full code :

```
<?php 
            error_reporting(0);
            include "../config/koneksi.php";
            include "../config/library.php";

            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $line_1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loading_plan WHERE line='1' ORDER BY id_loading asc");
            $total_hr_21 = Array(); 
            while ($l1=mysql_fetch_array($line_1)){

            $est_time_wobal = $l1[qty_wo] / $l1[uph];
            $est_time_wofk  = $l1[bal_fk] / $l1[uph];
            $total_hr       = $est_time_wobal + $est_time_wofk + $l1[setup_time];
            $kit_to_ship    = ((abs(strtotime ($l1[ship_date]) - strtotime ($l1[susbstore_date])))/(60*60*24));
            $balance_days   = ((abs(strtotime ($l1[ship_date]) - strtotime ($tgl_sekarang)))/(60*60*24));
            $q_days         = ((abs(strtotime ($tgl_sekarang) - strtotime ($l1[susbstore_date])))/(60*60*24));
            $total_hr_21[]  = $total_hr; 

?>

    <tr>
       <td><?php echo "Line#".$l1[line]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[no_run]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[susbstore_date]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[no_prog]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[product_number]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[product_desc]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[wo]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[qty_wo]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[bal_wo]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[bal_fk]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[uph]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo round($est_time_wobal,2); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo round($est_time_wofk,2); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[setup_time]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo round($total_hr,2); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[type_solder]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $l1[ship_date]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $kit_to_ship; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $q_days; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo array_sum($total_hr_21); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo "&nbsp;"; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo "&nbsp;"; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks, For help :)

Comment: where is addition in your code?

Comment: try this.... $line_1=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM loading_plan WHERE line='1' ORDER BY id_load asc");
$total_hr_21 = Array();
while ($l1=mysql_fetch_array($line_1)){
$total_hr_21[] = $l1[total_hr];
}
echo array_sum($total_hr_21);

Comment: hour calculation .... view this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format

Comment: yes! it works. thanks Karthick Kumar..

Comment: @KarthickKumar You're using `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. Which should be used, but the O.P. isn't using that. Also, your parameter for `mysqli_query` is incorrect. The first parameter should be a resourse returned by `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yap.. i just need add array_sum($total_hr_21); on my code.