# Adding multiple times PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am building an online timesheet for employees. At the end of the timesheet I need to show the total hours:mins worked.

I have the hours worked as variables:

```
$MondaysActual 
$TuesdaysActual 
$WednesdaysActual 
$ThursdaysActual 
$FridaysActual
```

The data held is something like `07:20` - the employee worked 7 hours 20 mins

How can I simply add these 5 times together and show the total as hrs:mins?

Comment: Could you please specify what have you tried and why it wasn't working for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format - probably duplicate

Comment: @Alex - Tried this but the result returns nothing

Comment: What exactly you've tried (codebase)? What the result you've got? What the errors were? What the specific env you use? The more specific question is - the simpler is to find the answer. Also, consider review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: from what `we` can see, you have tried to enter 5 variable names in some unspecified text editor, and posted that here.  You have not tried coding to solve your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   $times = array();


$times[] = "12:59";
$times[] = "0:58";
$times[] = "0:02";

// pass the array to the function
echo AddPlayTime($times);

function AddPlayTime($times) {
    $minutes = 0; //declare minutes either it gives Notice: Undefined variable
    // loop throught all the times
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
        $minutes += $hour * 60;
        $minutes += $minute;
    }

    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
    $minutes -= $hours * 60;

    // returns the time already formatted
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
}
```