# how to get sum of the total time in php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i working with the attendance management system.i calculate how many hours work done in employees.i already calculate the how much hours working in day and it store in the mysql database.

```
$totaltime = (strtotime($time_out) - strtotime($time_in));

                $hours = sprintf('%02d', intval($totaltime / 3600));

                $seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 

                $minutes = sprintf('%02d', intval($seconds_remain / 60));   
                $seconds = sprintf('%02d' ,($seconds_remain - ($minutes * 60)));

                $final = '';

                if ($time_in == '' || $time_out == '')
                {
                    $final = '';
                }
                else
                {
                    $final .= $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
                }
```

for example

```
$time_in = 08:09:57
$time_out = 16:04:50
$final = 07:54:53 (total working hours)
```

now i want to get the current month total working time for each employee.how do get sum of the $final using php?
sample data of the month_data

```
Emp_no  Date    Time_in Time_out    Total_hours TranID  
23  2019-08-01  07:54:40    16:01:40    08:07:00    1   
23  2019-08-02  07:42:35    16:02:53    08:20:18    2
```

i want get the sum of the Total_hours for related one employee

Comment: Could you provide us with the table structure you're using?

Comment: okay.i will update

Comment: Do you need the total working time or hours only?

Comment: no i want hours ,min,second bro

Comment: PD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask me this can be easily done using plain MySQL, no meed for PHP to calculate this.

You could take a look at a query somewhat like this

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(`Total_hours`) ) FROM `month_data` GROUP BY `Emp_no`;
```

there is a simple `SUM` function which can do this for you, it returns the total time in seconds though.

In order to turn that into readable time you can use the MySQL function `SEC_TO_TIME`.

***edit***

If the said column is not a `TIME` column you can CAST it to be handled as this type of column using `CAST()` the needed SQL would look something like

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CAST(`Total_hours` AS TIME)) ) FROM `month_data` GROUP BY `Emp_no`;
```

My suggestion would be to change the column type to `TIME` though.

***edit 2***

I was under the assumption that `SUM()` would be smart enough to convert the time to seconds and come up with the correct sum of the given times.

Not sure why yet but this is not the case, therefore you need to convert the given times to seconds first.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`Total_hours`)) ) FROM `month_data` GROUP BY `Emp_no`;
```

Now I have not tested this but `TIME_TO_SEC()` seems to accept `VARCHAR` just fine so need to `CAST()` the column anymore.

Comment: bro.it not get the correct out put. i think problem is Total_hours data type is VARCHAR not date

Comment: you could `CAST` it to the correct format, like `CAST(`Total_hours` AS TIME)`

Comment: but i can't put data type as date

Comment: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CAST('Total_hours` AS TIME)) ) FROM `month_data` GROUP BY `Emp_no`;

Comment: thank you very much bro .Your solution is work perfectly.

Comment: much appreciated for your value contribution.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Comment: bro. related to emp no 23  i got the total hours of 201:38:17 but it is incorrect .why ??

Comment: @NipunSachinda, please check the updated answer under `edit 2`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

```
echo OverallTime($allTimes);

$allTimes = array();
function OverallTime($allTimes) {
$minutes = 0;
foreach ($allTimes as $time) {
    list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
    $minutes += $hour * 60;
    $minutes += $minute;
}
$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$minutes -= $hours * 60;

return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
```

Comment: use it on your Total_hours

Comment: you have to echo function OverallTime($allTimes);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$total = [
    '00:02:55',
    '00:07:56',
    '01:03:32',
    '01:13:34',
    '02:13:44',
    '03:08:53',
    '03:13:54'
];

$sum = strtotime('00:00:00');
$sum2=0;
foreach ($total as $v){
    $sum1=strtotime($v)-$sum;
    $sum2 = $sum2+$sum1;
}
$sum3=$sum+$sum2;
echo date("H:i:s",$sum3);
?>
```

Comment: i want to get the second also bro

Comment: it need some kind of loop process. otherwise i cant catch all the date total hours

Comment: check now in a loop.

Comment: this also work also .thank you very much for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to someone looking for this, this is what I use on my music website. This code gets the duration in seconds of all the songs in an album, adds them up, and returns the total album length in hh mm ss.

```
$record_id = $this->record->id; <!--variable for record-->
.$query = 'SELECT SUM(duration) FROM #__songs WHERE `record_id` = '. $db->quote( (int) $record_id ); <!--selects the duration of all the songs in the album-->
$db->setQuery($query);  
$results = $db->loadResult();
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $results); <!--echo total time in hh mm ss.-->
```

Not an expert here. If you see something, say something XD