# How to add time which is coming from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
[
  {"duration":"00:01:46"},
  {"duration":"00:01:23"}, 
  {"duration":"00:01:56"},
  {"duration":"00:03:20"}, 
  {"duration":"00:05:41"},
  {"duration":"00:02:08"}
]
[
  {"duration":"00:01:32"},
  {"duration":"00:03:31"}, 
  {"duration":"00:05:56"},
  {"duration":"00:03:56"}, 
  {"duration":"00:03:47"},
  {"duration":"00:03:38"},
  {"duration":"00:02:26"}
]
```

This is the duration which is coming from my database column duration and now i want to add/sum of these all so i can display it.

Comment: this is invalid json by the way

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681725/how-to-sum-n-number-of-time-hhmm-format

Comment: How to sum this two times coming from database 
0:16:14
0:24:46

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime, its add method with DateInterval.

```
<?php

$a = '[
  {"duration":"00:01:46"},
  {"duration":"00:01:23"}, 
  {"duration":"00:01:56"},
  {"duration":"00:03:20"}, 
  {"duration":"00:05:41"},
  {"duration":"00:02:08"}
]';

$b = '[
  {"duration":"00:01:32"},
  {"duration":"00:03:31"}, 
  {"duration":"00:05:56"},
  {"duration":"00:03:56"}, 
  {"duration":"00:03:47"},
  {"duration":"00:03:38"},
  {"duration":"00:02:26"}
]';

$dataA = json_decode($a);

$dataB = json_decode($b);

function sum(array $data): string {
  $sum = new DateTime('00:00');
  $start = new DateTime('00:00');
  foreach ($data as $row) {
    $parts = explode(':', $row->duration);
    $start->add(new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%sH%sM%sS', $parts[0], $parts[1], $parts[2])));
  }

  return $start->diff($sum)->format('%H:%I:%S');
}

var_dump(sum($dataA));
var_dump(sum($dataB));
```

Output:

```
string(8) "00:16:14"
string(8) "00:24:46"
```

Note: you would have to display also days if your duration sums to more than 24 hours.